# SPI Problem with K-Thermocouple and Potentiometer?

Tags: arduino-uno, spi, potentiometer

[image: Results of both K-Thermocouple by itself and the whole circuit together][image: A diagram of my circuit]I have a setup where the Arduino reads input from the k-thermocouple and uses that info to regultate the an output voltage through a potentiometer. I know the potentiometer is not faulty because able to read the output from the wiper when I run the program but for some reason, k-thermocouple is stuck at 0 Celsius. I know that the k-thermocouple is not faulty either because it works accordingly when I run a program specifically by itself.

Does anybody know why there is a problem with how the k-thermocouple is operating in junction with the potentiometer? Here is a declarations of my program.

```
#include <SPI.h>

// K-couple dependent DigiPot Regulator

#include "SPI.h"
#include "max6675.h"

byte address = 0x10;
int CLK = 13;
int CS = 10;
int SDI = 11;
const int ktcSO = 12;
int ktcCS = 9;
int ktcCLK = 13;

MAX6675 ktc(ktcCLK, ktcCS, ktcSO);


int digitalPotWrite(int value) //Everything that happens when the DigiPot is 
called
{
  digitalWrite(CS, LOW); // Chip Select is ACTIVE LOW (so now it's selected)
  SPI.transfer(address);
  SPI.transfer(value);
  digitalWrite(CS, HIGH);
}

void setup() 
{
  SPI.begin();
  pinMode (CLK, OUTPUT);
  pinMode (CS, OUTPUT);
  pinMode (SDI, OUTPUT);
  Serial.begin(9600);
  // give the MAX a little time to settle
  delay(500);
}

void loop() 
{
  if (ktc.readFahrenheit() < 60)  // While it's still in Safe Zone
  {
    digitalPotWrite(255);
    // Show the current temp in C and F
    Serial.print("Deg C = "); 
    Serial.print(ktc.readCelsius());
    Serial.print("\t Deg F = ");
    Serial.print(ktc.readFahrenheit());
    int sensorValue = analogRead(A0);
    float voltage = sensorValue * (5.0 / 1023.0);
    Serial.print("\t V = ");
    Serial.println(voltage);
    int clockValue = analogRead(A1);
    Serial.print("\t Clock = ");
    Serial.println(clockValue);
  }
        if (ktc.readFahrenheit() < 65) // While in Caution Zone
        digitalPotWrite(51);
        else if (ktc.readFahrenheit() < 70)
        digitalPotWrite(102);
        else if (ktc.readFahrenheit() < 75)
        digitalPotWrite(153);
        else if (ktc.readFahrenheit() < 78)
        digitalPotWrite(184);
        else if (ktc.readFahrenheit() < 80) //Getting into Danger Zone
        digitalPotWrite(204);
        else if (ktc.readFahrenheit() < 81)
        digitalPotWrite(214);
        else if (ktc.readFahrenheit() < 82)
        digitalPotWrite(224);
        else if (ktc.readFahrenheit() < 83)
        digitalPotWrite(235);
        else if (ktc.readFahrenheit() < 84)
        digitalPotWrite(245);
        else (ktc.readFahrenheit() < 85); //Complete Shutoff 
        digitalPotWrite(255);
    {
     Serial.print("Deg C = "); 
     Serial.print(ktc.readCelsius());
     Serial.print("\t Deg F = ");
     Serial.print(ktc.readFahrenheit());
     int sensorValue = analogRead(A0);
     float voltage = sensorValue * (5.0 / 1023.0);
     Serial.print("\t V = ");
     Serial.println(voltage);
     int clockValue = analogRead(A1);
     Serial.print("\t Clock = ");
     Serial.println(clockValue);
    }
}
```

Also, the code I used to test the K-Thermocouple is one that can be found on the internet (with just a little bit of adjustments)...

```
// Sample Arduino MAX6675 Arduino Sketch

#include "max6675.h"

int ktcSO = 12;
int ktcCS = 9;
int ktcCLK = 13;

MAX6675 ktc(ktcCLK, ktcCS, ktcSO);


void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600);
  // give the MAX a little time to settle
  delay(500);
}

void loop() {
  // basic readout test

   Serial.print("Deg C = "); 
   Serial.print(ktc.readCelsius());
   Serial.print("\t Deg F = ");
   Serial.println(ktc.readFahrenheit());
   int clockValue = analogRead(A1);
    Serial.print("\t Clock = ");
    Serial.println(clockValue);

   delay(500);
}
```

Comment: Please edit your question to include a circuit diagram.  Which lines do you have pullups on? What do you have connected to MISO, dig. pin 12?  Do you have an oscilloscope to check the clock signal during temperature reads, or to check data bits at MISO during reads?

Comment: Yes, I have MISO connected to pin 12. When I run a program to test the K-Thermocouple itself, I do get a square wave clock signal on the oscilloscope but then when I run the program above, the clock signal is indiscernible. It looks like a complete noise.

Comment: What's attached to A1?  Why is `clockValue` reading differently in the two sketches?

Comment: I think that may be the cause of my problem. When I had it hooked up to an oscilloscope, I was getting a pulse wave for the first one but the second one was complete static and indiscernible. This is what leads me to believe that the issue is rooted from the CLK signal of SPI with both the K-Thermocouple and the DigiPot in conjunction.

Answer (score 1):

The wiring diagram, if accurate, shows a couple of problems.

First, A0 has nothing attached to it, so `sensorValue` may read in as zero or some small random number.

Second, attaching the digital pot's analog output pin 6, P1W, to the Uno's digital input pin 12 is pointless.  Instead connect P1W to whatever it is supposed to control.  If you want to handle data *from* the MCP42X1, connect its pin 13, SDO, to an Uno input.

However, neither of those problems appears to be related to misreading the MAX6675 temperature.  I don't know of a good approach to solving that problem, but if I were working with the circuit, would remove the wire between P1W and the Uno's digital pin 12, and would use 12 as the input from the MAX6675; that is, would wire it to d12 instead of d8, and instead of `int ktcSO = 8` would say `const int ktcSO = 12`.  Also, I'd probably replace the bit of code

```
  }
  else
  {
    while (ktc.readFahrenheit() < 85) 
      {
```

with just a closing `}`.  In the Arduino paradigm, `loop()` runs repeatedly, and the if–else sequence adequately guards each of the `digitalPotWrite()` calls.

Note, the `digitalPotWrite()` function should be defined or declared before any calls to it appear.  Instead of placing that function at the end, put it before  `loop()` or before `setup()`.

Comment: My mistake on the A0. I originally had it there and switched it to D12 sometime during my troubleshooting process.

One question tho... I'm assuming your're saying I should replace the highlighted portion with 

"}  loop()"

but wouldn't the program get stuck in loop the moment it enters it?

Comment: Looks like I read it wrong. No additional loop.

Comment: jwpat7 So I've applied all the changes that you suggested and the MAX6675 is still not registering any input. Side note: I have P1W connected to A0 so that I can monitor my output and also don't pay any mind to Vdd and Vss. I have them correctly connected in my circuit.

Comment: I added a few lines of code to try and show the clock signals (D13 <--> pin 2) of the MAX6675 when tested by itself and the whole circuit. There is some form of signal output every loop for the MAX6675 test itself but there is no signal when tested for the whole circuit.

Comment: The reason for replacing those five lines of code is that (1) your program will get stuck in the `while (ktc.readFahrenheit() < 85)` loop if `readFahrenheit()` isn't working or if you aren't changing the temperature at the sensor.  If it's stuck in that `while` loop, it won't produce any output.  And (2), decoupling the rest of `loop()` from its first 15 lines simplifies figuring out what it is doing.

Comment: I don't get exactly what you mean by  “some form of signal output every loop for the MAX6675 test itself but there is no signal when tested for the whole circuit” – in particular, it isn't clear to me whether your  “MAX6675 test itself” just loads and runs a specialized MAX6675-testing sketch, leaving the wiring as is, or whether you change just the hardware, or if you change both.  Given my lack of understanding of that, I don't know if you should be looking for a hardware issue or software.  Does all the hardware work ok if you run specialized test sketches, leaving the wiring as is?

Comment: Yes, that's exactly what is it. I ran a specialized testing sketch for the MAX6675 alone with the wiring as is and it works just fine. That's what the first side of the result picture shows. The right side is the output of the whole circuit. I added a few lines of code to print out the clock signal (value) during each loop since I don't have an oscilloscope at hand at the moment and I don't know how else to display the Serial CLK through my Arduino IDE.

Comment: I didn't see those outputs when I was editing my answer.  Anyhow, if you add the exact code for the left side output, and the exact code for the right side output to the question, I'll look at the code again.  Can you update the circuit diagram to match what you have, with A0 connection fixed?

Comment: I updated the circuit diagram and included the changes suggested in the main code as well as including the code used to test the K-Thermocouple.